# what's the meaning of the Android trace log fields

Tags: android, format, logging, trace, ddms

I used DDMS profiling tool and get a trace log (.trace). And I converted .trace file to **.txt** file using `'traceview -r ddms349082309823084.trace > sample.txt'.`

But, I cannot understand exact meaning of each fields in the text file. please refer to blow example.

```
id thread  global start,end   method

 9    205      199      208 + android/os/Debug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z

 9    208      202      205 + dalvik/system/VMDebug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z

 9    211      205        0   dalvik/system/VMDebug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z

 9    214      208        0   android/os/Debug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z

 9    225      219      222 + org/apache/harmony/dalvik/ddmc/Chunk.<init> (I[BII)V

 9    228      222        0   org/apache/harmony/dalvik/ddmc/Chunk.<init> (I[BII)V
```

is there anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use **traceview** to view the trace log (.trace), so that you could get a nice UI to understand it!

More info about **Traceview Layout**, please refer to:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

If you want to know details about trace logs, you could also refer in this page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html#format